# JFrame and JPanel centering

Tags: java, swing

I was wondering how would I add a `JPanel` to a `JFrame` and make sure it is centered and had a gap of set size on either sides? I can get it in the center but it sticks to the edge.

Comment: @Reimeus I would understand that if it would help answer the question but all I would post in relation to this would be window.add(componenet) and I don't see how that would help?

Comment: question is fix gap for JFrame (aka Borders) or fix JPanels size or ???, without this details couldn't be answered properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a Border layout.  Put the JPanel in the center, then use Box.createHorizontalStrut(size) and Box.createVerticalStrut(size) in the east/west and north/south locations, respectively.

something like:  (from memory, might not be exactly right)

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
int gap = 20;  //or whatever
frame.getContentFrame().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(gap), BorderLayout.EAST);
panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(gap), BorderLayout.WEST);
panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(gap), BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(gap), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```